# Unit test failing on Xcode 14.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xctest

I am unable to run Unit Test targets for any project on my xcode 14.1 with iOS Simulator version 13.7

Assertions: System: Failed to install or launch the test runner.

Underlying Error: Process spawn via launchd failed. Bad file descriptor. (Underlying Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Mach error 9 - (os/kern) memory failure))

```
Details

Process spawn via launchd failed.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 9
Failure Reason: Bad file descriptor
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-04-26 21:17:18 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    Session = "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.32CA512F-AF12-4E75-B34C-D43C9AB75CDE";
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Mach error 9 - (os/kern) memory failure)
Domain: NSMachErrorDomain
Code: 9
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone12,5";
    "device_osBuild" = "13.7 (17H22)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Test;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = "x86_64";
    "operation_duration_ms" = 59;
    "operation_errorCode" = 9;
    "operation_errorDomain" = NSPOSIXErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 0;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 3;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 0;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.tool";
    "param_runnable_type" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 1;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator16.1";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.1";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.3.1 (Build 22E261)
Xcode 14.1 (21534.1) (Build 14B47b)
Timestamp: 2023-04-26T23:17:18+02:00
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you file a Radar for this?

Comment: No issue, I just switched to a different simulator, and it works on other versions. @NachoSoto Try switching to diff simulator, like iPhone 14 Pro Max with iOS 16.1